# Loopin' multiplication in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making this program that asks you for a number then prints out the first 1000 terms of that number's times table. I'm using Python 3x The output should be:

[image: http://snag.gy/KxM37.jpg]

But instead it gives me this: [image: http://snag.gy/SQTAe.jpg]

This is the code:

```
multiplication = 0
firstnumber = int(input("Enter a number: "))
number = firstnumber
for j in range(0, 1001):
    for i in range(0, 1001):
        multiplication = multiplication+1
    number = number*multiplication
    print(str(multiplication) + " times " + str(firstnumber) + " is " + str(number))
```

Thanks

Comment: why are there two loops?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/

Comment: @dm03514: If there shouldn't be, please improve it and answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: You’re doing the factorial of 1–1000 times 1001^1000. That’s kind of fun. Anyways, it looks like it should be `firstnumber * multiplication`, not `number * multiplication`.

Comment: Change the `1001` to a smaller number like `5` and you'll probably see what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Why has it been downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it might be the statement "I had no idea what to do, so I tried with two loops."  Many people on this site expect a minimal level of understanding of the problem.  That makes it sound like instead of thinking critically of the problem, you were just throwing things at it, not sure what would happen.

Comment: @SethMMorton: I tried different ways though they did not work and I thought that two loops would be better (this is not a lie).

Comment: That's fine... I personally was not offended or moved to downvote.  You asked why you were downvoted and I took a guess as to why.

Comment: Of course you didn't! Obviously this isn't a question and annoyment forum. You even took the time to look at this page - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you update `number` and keep multiplying it. You foresaw this problem and created a variable called `firstnumber` to tackle it, but you forgot to use it. Here’s what you meant to do:

```
>>> multiplication = 0
>>> firstnumber = int(input("Enter a number: "))
Enter a number: 17
>>> number = firstnumber
>>> number = firstnumber
>>> for j in range(0, 1001):
...     for i in range(0, 1001):
...         multiplication = multiplication+1
...         number = firstnumber * multiplication
...         print(str(multiplication) + " times " + str(firstnumber) + " is " + str(number))
... 
1 times 17 is 17
2 times 17 is 34
3 times 17 is 51
4 times 17 is 68
5 times 17 is 85
6 times 17 is 102
7 times 17 is 119
8 times 17 is 136
9 times 17 is 153
10 times 17 is 170
11 times 17 is 187
12 times 17 is 204
13 times 17 is 221
14 times 17 is 238
15 times 17 is 255
16 times 17 is 272
```

You  are likely, however, much better off, to do something like this:

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
mult = int(input("How many multiples: "))
for i in range(mult+1):
    print("%d times %d is %d" %(number, i, number*i))
```

Comment: Why are there two loops?

Comment: @minitech: because that’s only very mildly related to the problem. I was trying to demonstrate the biger problems in OP’s code first. The next edit was going to contain an optimized version of what OP wants.

Comment: When I try what you told me, it won't work, it gives this: Enter a number: 1
1001 times 1 is 1001
2002 times 1 is 2002
3003 times 1 is 3003
4004 times 1 is 4004
5005 times 1 is 5005
6006 times 1 is 6006
7007 times 1 is 7007 What should I do?

Comment: I wanted 1 times by 1 is 1, 2 times by 1 is 2

Comment: @Discovery So, if this answer doesn't give you what you want for a result, is it better than dm03514's answer?

Comment: @SethMMorton: Ok, I'll give dm03514's answer a go.

Comment: @Discovery: What I posted is an actual copy of my python terminal. So I’m going to suggest that accidentally ran something that wasn’t my code, thinking it was

Comment: Well, actually 1002001 times.

Comment: What numbers did you input?

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to think through the problem before trying to start coding.

You have the first step: Get a number from the user

I think the second step consists of going from 0 To 1000 and multiplying that number. In psuedo-code:

```
users_number = some_number
for num from 0 - 1000:
  print(num * usernumber)
```

Comment: Your answer nor the other works. I might choose this one if you explain to me why this error happened: for num from 0 - 1000:
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Discovery, It is not valid python, it is fake code, since you are learning i left as an exercise to you to actually write the correct python!:)

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best code, but better than what you were trying.

```
given_number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
for multiplier in range(1,1001):
    print("{0:4} times {1} is {2}".format(multiplier, given_number, multiplier*given_number))
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote up though I wanted much more simpler code. Thanks anyway

Comment: Well, I just added a bit of string formatting to prettify the output which you can see when you run my script. The numbers 0, 1, 2 represent the indices of the arguments passed to the format method. And, helping is priority. :)